# Form doesn't shrink when width of input becomes smaller in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I made this small code with javascript:

```
function clicksearchicon(searchbar) {
var searchbar = document.getElementById(searchbar),
searchbar_class = searchbar.className;
if(searchbar_class == "searchbar_hidden"){
    searchbar.className = "searchbar";
    return false;
}
else{
    if(searchbar.value == '' || searchbar.value == searchbar.defaultValue){
        searchbar.className = "searchbar_hidden";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

the html:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" onsubmit="return clicksearchicon('searchbar')">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search..." class="searchbar_hidden" id="searchbar" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and the css:

```
.searchbar_hidden {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
width: 0px !important;
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 0px !important;
opacity: 0;
}

.searchbar {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
width: 130px !important;
opacity: 1;
}
```

everything works perfect in Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera, but in Safari the form doesn't shrink when the input field is hidden, and the submit button will float left with a large margin on the right. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Making a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, it seems to be changed by the ID value. I have fixed it with a quick and dirty solution. Very straightforward, just to show you the behavior. Works for me: see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tvrjb/9/).

HTML:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" class="searchbar_hidden" onsubmit="return clicksearchicon('searchbar')" width="1" >
    <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="" class="searchbar_hide" id="searchbar" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="Submit" name="nameSubmit" id="idButton_Submit" value="Submit"  alt="Submit Button"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
clicksearchicon = function(searchbar){
    var searchbar = document.getElementById(searchbar);
    if(searchbar == null){
        var searchbar = document.getElementById('searchbar_show');
    }
    searchbar_class = searchbar.className;
    if(searchbar_class == "searchbar_hide"){
        searchbar.className = "searchbar_show";
        searchbar.id = "searchbar_show";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(searchbar.value == '' || searchbar.value == searchbar.defaultValue){
        searchbar.className = "searchbar_hide";
        searchbar.id = "searchbar";
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

CSS:

```
#searchbar {
    width:1px;
}

#searchbar_show {
    width:130px;
}


.searchbar_hidden .searchbar_hide {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
width: 0x !important;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
border:none;
opacity: 0;
}

.searchbar_hidden .searchbar_show {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease;
-o-transition: all 1s ease;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease;
transition: all 1s ease;
width: 130px;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: it solves the problem I mentioned in the post, but if I use display: none;, the transition doesn't work anymore :(